# I have a vehicle tracking device. Iwant to track the location of my device in a google map integrated in my asp.net application.How can I achieve it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a vehicle tracking device. I want to track the location of my device in a google map integrated in my asp.net application.How can I achieve it?

Comment: Writing some code would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

The First way is to use online database; your location device will send this data as latitude and longitude to database, this data will then be fetched by your asp.net application which than you can use as you please. The advantage of using database will be that you'll have last known location of vehicle, You can also look into the pattern of travelling which again in case could be very useful when it come to predicting the final location of vehicle, if in case is lost or stolen. Disadvantage it's kind of slow process, could be very heavy on database too.

The second way would be to use web service the only difference will rather than using database to store latitude and longitude the data will be send a fetched at the same time by the help of web service. Advantage it's fast and it doesn't take much of memory. Disadvantage, you wont have any record to determine where was last known location of vehicle.

Third way the best would be to use this both together and store data which is most necessary rather than storing all the data in database. This way it will be fast as well as it'll give you the feature of history keeping.

Comment: How can my device send the data?? Any idea sir

Comment: Can you state which device are you using ?